# Checkbox values and useBean tag

Tags: java, forms, checkbox, model, jstl

I'm a jstl newbie so probably this question will sound to you funny. 
Anyway, I have a model with a List as property and I'd like to fill this with a list of values (chosen from a list of checkboxes). I'm using the useBean tag in the form-processing jstl page, but doing this:

```
<jsp:useBean id='subscription' class='Subscription'>
<c:set target='${subscription}' property='priviledge' value='${param.priviledge}'/>
```

Where the property priviledge is a List and $param.priviledge the values of a series of checkboxes, I get a

```
javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: Attempt to convert String "ads"  to type "[Ljava.lang.String;", but there is no PropertyEditor for that type
```

"ads" is one of the values I have selected. I thought the values of the priviledge field was already a List but it seems it works in a different way. I tried to iterate through the $param.priviledge object and I get all the values with no problem.

How can I use this list to fill a List?

Thanks for any help.
Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attempt to convert String "ads"  to type "[Ljava.lang.String;"

This error suggests that the setter is `setPriviledge(String[] arr)`, not a `java.util.List`.

The values in the `param` map are Strings; to get all the values as an array, use the `paramValues` map.

```
${paramValues.priviledge}
```

The property on the `Subscription` bean would need to be a String array:

```
  private String[] priviledge;

  public String[] getPriviledge() {
    return priviledge;
  }

  public void setPriviledge(String[] priviledge) {
    this.priviledge = priviledge;
  }
```

*(I don't know if you've simplified the code to post here, but you should not use the default package - many web servers won't like it and won't be able to instantiate your `Subscription` class.)*

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the explanation, didn't know about the paramValues object.

ps: yes I wrote it simplified, my model is not using the default package :)